# remove blinking on my hover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

To be simple I added a jquery function that allow me to insert an element to add an image to the menu:

`$('.menu-item').append('<div class="hover--state"><img src="http://myway-hannover.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hover-state-menu.png" /> </div>');`

When the append is done this will be the layout of my menu.

```
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="hover--state">
           <img src="http://myway-hannover.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hover-state-menu.png">
        </div>
    </li>
```

My css code for hovering:

```
#top-menu-nav > ul > li > a:hover + div{
     display: block;
}
```

The image that I append its a shadow image of a menu when the state is on hover, so every time when the state is hover the image will be displayed which I added a `display: block` and when there is no hovering happen the image will be `display: none`.

The hover state are already done but there is a blingking every hover that I made. You can check the blinking hover on this link http://myway-hannover.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your jQuery function - this is a CSS issue.

What's happening right now is, when the hover state is activated, it covers the `<a>` element, which then deactivates the hover state. You want to make sure the hover state remains activated when the shadow image is present. You can do this by moving the hover detection onto the `<li>` level like this:

change

```
#top-menu-nav > ul > li > a:hover + div {
  ...
}
```

to

```
#top-menu-nav > ul > li:hover > .hover--state {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The hover image is not showing when I used the this `#top-menu-nav > ul > li:hover > .hover--state` @feihcsim

Comment: i just noticed i made an error in my original edit, but i just fixed it. Use two dashes in your selector, not one. That's `hover--state`, not `hover-state`

Comment: there's a problem I can't click the any menu's but the hover is working fine.

Comment: that's expected because, just as was happening before, your `.hover--state` is _covering_ your `a` element. make sure your `a` element isn't blocked behind the shadow image by moving it below the element in the HTML:
`<li><div class="hover--state></div><a>Home</a></li>`

Comment: you mean the `hover--state` class are first then the `a` tag?

Comment: yep - that's what's in my comment. by the way, you should know that you can test these changes directly in your browser's inspector